# (Xamarin.Forms) System.ArgumentException: Couldn't bind to method 'GetOnServiceConnectedHandler'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, accessibilityservice

I am trying to implement AccessibilityService like below (Xamarin Forms+ VisualStudio 2015):

```
[Service(Label = "myApp", Permission = Manifest.Permission.BindAccessibilityService)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" })]
public class MyAccessibilityService: AccessibilityService
{
     ...
     ...
      protected override void OnServiceConnected()
     {
         ...
         ...
     }
}
```

But i am getting runtime error `System.ArgumentException: Couldn't bind to method 'GetOnServiceConnectedHandler'.`

And breakpoint set inside `OnServiceConnected` method, does not hit.

Note: All permissions are given in .Droid project properties, so it should not be permissions issue.

Any pointer will be greatly helpful.

Comment: If anyone has a sample implementation of AccessibilityService in Xamarin, that will also be great :)